# Problema para ler formulas usando o Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Estou criando um método para ocultar os elementos que estão zerados de um arquivo excel, mas o problema que ele não consegue pegar os valores quando a coluna é uma formula. Como posso fazer para pegar esses valores?

Meu código:

```
private static ByteArrayOutputStream ocultarZerados(ByteArrayOutputStream arquivo) throws Exception
{
    InputStream arquivoExcel = new ByteArrayInputStream(arquivo.toByteArray());
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(arquivoExcel);


    XSSFSheet s = (XSSFSheet) wb.getSheetAt(1);

    for (Row linha : s)
    {
        System.out.println("===================");

        for (Cell coluna : linha)
        {
            if(coluna.getCellType() == 1)
            {
                System.out.print(coluna.getStringCellValue() + "|");
            }
            else {
                System.out.print(coluna.getNumericCellValue() + "|");
            }
        }

        System.out.println("===================");
    }

    wb.write(arquivo);
    wb.close();

    return arquivo;
}
```

Comment: Fiz o teste utilizando o poi 3.17 e funcionou normalmente. Caso ainda não tenha conseguido resolver o problema, se puder, disponibilize uma planilha que reproduza essa problema.